# Does aesthetic metal plated armor exist for mages in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

This is an aesthetic question, rather than a stats question. I have searched the internet to find any mage armor that has sometime of metal plate attachments for the battle-mage look for my mage character, but I have come up dry. I read forums suggesting pauldron schematic attachments, but I do not think those exist. I cannot even find any pictures of mage-armor on the web. I have traveled to the armor schematic merchant in Val Royeaux, and found only leathery looking schematic armor. I am also discovering that some mage armors cannot be worn by the Qunari.

Does aesthetic metal plated armor exist for mages in Dragon Age Inquisition? If it exists, what must be done to obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading somewhere (having trouble finding the source now), that each character has their own unique armor model. Basically, whatever item you equip on your Inquisitor - it will always look similar (except for colors). Equipping the same item to one of your companions, will make it look like their personal model.

Due to this fact, it is not possible to have a plate armor look for your mage, since the mage unique armor looks for you and your companions are generally cloth-like.

There's a masterwork item that removes the armor requirement on the crafted item, effectively allowing a mage to wear heavy armor. However, due to the fact stated above (which I tested in-game, to my disappointment), the look of the armor will change to your character's unique look.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am not sure if this is related: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718650-dragon-age-inquisition/70641797 ; This link suggests that a masterwork craft is restricted to a 40% chance of happening the first time, bypassing save restarting? By the way where and how does one obtain a masterwork item?

Comment: I'm not sure where the specific masterwork item I mentioned is found, but generally I've noticed they are rare finds on regular materials. For example, every one in a while, an Iron Vein would yield Fade-Touched Iron, which is the masterwork equivalent. I think I've also had some drop from "elite" enemies, and dragons. They all come with different properties.

Comment: Interesting, that explains the fade-touched stuff I was finding. What about the 40% chance of crafting, does that restriction exist?

Comment: In a way, yes. There are two types of masterwork items - the first kind gives you a % change to give the item's stats a 10% boost. Basically, you have a chance to give the existing stats on the item a 10% boost. I've seen these items with 10, 20, 30, 40 and 100% chance on them. The second kind of masterwork items give a special ability to the item. This type of masterwork item is always applied, there's no chance it will fail. The abilities range from casting Immolate, to giving a damage buff for a short amount of time.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a made a mistake to purchase the game for the ps4. It might have been possible to modify the look of the armor appearance in the game on the pc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of. If you craft armor with silverite (not necessarily the fade-touched masterwork, that is a bonus) as the main material, it removes class restrictions. The add-on schematics do exist, and are specific to the armor type (light, medium, and heavy). Mid-tier can be purchased at Val Royeaux, but can also be found 'in the wild', but you are at the mercy of the RNG on that front. After certain plot events, new areas will become available which have merchants who will sell you better schematics.

If you are looking for an early-game armor-like look, there *are* leg and arm addons that look like plate for the mage gear, but I do not think they can be purchased, but just be found in the world.

Comment: Wow. Do you know of any good places to find silverite? Are they located in the level 12 or above regions? Thanks.

Comment: I'm about 80% sure you can find silverite in Emprise de Lion, though it will be somewhat rough at 12. You *may* be able to run the 'Resources from Emprise de Lion' operation at the war table to gather them.

Comment: I think I have small amounts of silverite from early finds. I am unsure how to gain access to Emprise de Lion, it may require a quest completion? Where did I find early access to silverite? Was it from the RNG or is there another place I am drawing a blank on?

Comment: Probably RNG. Just do the plot quests, it opens up relatively early (about 1/4 maybe?) I don't want to spoil anytging

Answer (score 1):

Enchanter Mail, for one, does have a metal breastplate. At least for my female, elven inquisitor mage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full heavy armor that is not a jacket with bits of metal. First you have to be human race, then go buy orlesian army heavy armor schematic from Val Royeaux. Use silverite in the main slot and bam! Mage in heavy armor! Orlesian armor is a preset look unlike almost every other amor set. Looks totally bad ass. Another one that is preset is warden armor. You can get the schematic from the danish camp in exalted plains. Best looking armor in my opinion, once again use silverite. (warden has no race lock). To correct what others have said there are some armors that will look the same across all characters and (warrior, rogue, mage) the only two I know of so far are Orlesian and Warden armor. Schematics are easy to get. Like I said before I recommend warden over Orlesian looks wise, it is also significantly cheaper. 900ish vs 3000ish.

Comment: Where can we get the warden armor schematics?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the Warden armor is not race locked. To clarify, the warden armor will have its full metal plated look, independent of race? My Qunari has had a tough time getting pass all of its preset clothing appearances.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that the Dragon Armor (even the light mage-friendly variety) is fully plated, and looks pretty bad-ass, particularly on a Qunari (though admittedly, I haven't tested it on a female). But I believe it's only a part of a pre-order bonus, and I'm not sure if it can be acquired independently

Answer (score 0):

The heavy armors do not provide the full plated metal armor look available for the female Qunari.

I traveled to the hissing planes to buy the tier 3 Battlemaster Armor. I traveled to the Exalted planes to obtain the Tier 2 Warden armor. Both can be made using regular silverite, with no class restrictions. However, when I crafted both the tier 3 Battlemaster Armor and  tier 2 warden armor and allowed each character to put on the armors, only my female Qunari character failed to show the full metal plated armor look. Instead she wore the mercenary armor from the beginning of the game using the warden armor, and she only wears a few metal pieces when she wears the Battlemaster armor.

I want to send a message to Bioware and EA that this needs to be fixed immediately. Players want to wear full plated armor on any character they choose, independent of race, gender, and possibly class.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good looking armour available but it requires some customizing with the Arms and Legs addons etc.

For example, Battlemage Mail combined with Battlemage Mail Arms and Battlemage Coat Legs looks amazing IMO, especially if you get the right colours. Add a hook onto it and it looks even better.

Battlemage Coat with the Coat addons can also look really damn sweet - the shoulders actually look similar to Corypheus'.

Answer (score 0):

Vanguard Mail has the plated metal look, if you use silverite you can use it on any character and it actually looks cool on a female Quinari mage.